# Error 0x80070032, Cant enable file history for shared folder.

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, backup, shared-folders

I have a shared folder in one machine and read/write access for that folder from another machine. On both machines File History is enabled. When I try to add that shared folder to File History folders I get this error:

[image]

Comment: `0x80070002` deals with Windows being unable to find a file.  The folder either did not present itself to the system when the backup was started, or the folder wasn't accessible the user profile.

Comment: I can easily access the folder using file explorer. The error code is Error 0x80070032

Comment: [Backup does not complete successfully: error 0x80070032](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/backup-does-not-complete-successfully-error/5dfcf65b-120f-4f8b-a423-d2cc2cf27461)

Comment: 0x80070032 = ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED , so it looks like MS doesn't allow what you want to do

Comment: @Ashot - That is the exact reason, the error code should, be in the body of the question.  I couldn't just double click on the text to search for it.